# email validation with regular expression, which supports all the validation for an email id

Tags: regex

i want a regular expression with supports the validation of a email id, the following emailids it should not support:

1. `1test@yopmail.com`
2. `test_test_@yopmail.com`
3. `test.123_abc@yopmail.com`

i am using the following regex:

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z]+[_*|.*]{1}[0-9a-zA-Z]*|[_*|.*]|[0-9a-zA-Z]*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$
```

but it doesnot show all the validation

can anyone please help me?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the addresses you dislike. I don't think you should reject somebody's email address just because of aesthetics. Some people don't get to pick their own address, and some have preferences different from yours.

Comment: `[_*|.*]{1}` isn't sane, and probably doesn't mean what you think. I guess you want `[_.]*` or perhaps `[_.]?`.

Comment: we cant use two underscore/dots or two special character, because these are invalid

Comment: !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}|~@some.example.org is a valid email address.

Comment: Also the scope of the alternation operators is different from what you expect. `^(a[b]|c[d]|e)$` matches `ab` or `cd` or `e`.

Comment: You call that an email validation regex? [**THIS**](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) is an email validation regex!

Answer (score 0):

got this which supports the all the validation of an email

^([a-z]+[0-9]*[_*|.*]?[a-z0-9]*)@[a-z]+(.[a-z]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$

Answer (score 0):

The following ought to do it for you :

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```